# Where did Edmond Malone place the Tempest in the chronology of Shakespeare's plays?

Tags: william-shakespeare, the-tempest

In an [excellent answer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/9638/2191) to one of my previous questions, verbose writes:

> Since *The Tempest* is the first play printed in the [First Folio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Folio), it was often assumed to be an early play. Scholars such as [Edmond Malone](http://www.oxforddnb.com/view/10.1093/ref:odnb/9780198614128.001.0001/odnb-9780198614128-e-17896) and [Edward Capell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Capell) began tackling the chronology of Shakespeare's plays in the late 1700s. I have been unable to track down exactly where Malone and Capell placed *The Tempest* chronologically, as I don't have easy access to a university library and could not find the information online.

Some scholars now assume that *The Tempest* was printed as the first play in the First Folio because of the quality of the text that the printer could work from. [Edmond Malone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmond_Malone) was the first scholar who tried to establish a chronology of Shakespeare's plays, namely in "An Attempt to Ascertain the Order in Which the Plays Attributed to Shakspeare Were Written", which was included in the first volume of *The Plays of William Shakspeare* (1778), a revised edition of Samuel Johnson's Shakespeare edition, created on co-operation with George Steevens.

The question is now where Malone put *The Tempest* in this first chronology. (He seems to have revised his chronology later; this question is specifically about the version published in 1778.)

Comment: There's a [copy on the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.512119/page/n281).

Comment: @GarethRees Heh, thanks. Some other link had take me to an edition from 1821. I can now answer my own question, I guess.

Comment: Correction, it’s not Malone’s edition. It’s Samuel Johnson and George Steevens’s. Malone contributed this essay and a lot of notes, but he’s merely one of the “various contributors” mentioned on page 6 at the link.

Comment: @verbose Thanks, I have edited my question to correct this.

Answer (score 8):

"An Attempt to Ascertain the Order in which the Plays Attributed to Shakespeare Were Written" can be found on pages 269 - 346 of the first volume of *The Plays of William Shakespeare in Ten Volumes*. The chronology itself can be found on pages 274-275. It starts with *Titus Andronicus* (1589) and ends with the following plays and years:

- *A Yorkshire Tragedy* (1608; title italicized since attribution to Shakespeare is doubtful)
- *Antony and Cleopatra* (1608)
- *Coriolanus* (1609)
- *Timon of Athens* (1610)
- *Othello* (1611)
- *The Tempest* (1612)
- *Twelfth Night* (1614)

Malone's arguments for dating *The Tempest* to 1612 can be found on [pages 341-342](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.512119/page/n353). These arguments include a "dreadful tempest" in England in late 1612 and the account of the sailor Edmond Pet, who narrowly survived a tempest at sea, but he eventually describes the dating of this play as "[not] a very improbable conjecture".

Comment: Oh cool! I’ll revise my answer to the other question based on this. Not sure how I missed finding this copy.